# Android Development with Eclipse (apk not found)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm trying to run a TestGame I made for testing to setup the work environment, but it won't "find the apk", I read many questions like this one on stackoverflow and over the internet and tried all of them, but none of them worked.

I tried removing the Build Automatically, nothing. Tried exporting and importing and nothing. Tried starting from 0 again and nothing. Looked if eclipse listed it as a library and it wasn't. Thought it was missing something and I downloaded everything from the SDK manager and still nothing.

I ran out of ideas of what it could be. It just displays:

```
[2013-10-01 22:03:47 - TestGame] ------------------------------
[2013-10-01 22:03:47 - TestGame] Android Launch!
[2013-10-01 22:03:47 - TestGame] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-01 22:03:47 - TestGame] Could not find TestGame.apk!
```

I tried compiling from another source and it worked. What can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A name change could cause this. Have you changed the name? Is there an APK in your bin folder? What's it called?

Comment: No I didn't change the name, I checked the manifest if it was pointing to the wrong class, but it was correct. there is no apk on the bin folder nor the gen folder, just a compiled class on the bin folder that is MainActivity.class.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the problem, sorry. It sounds like Eclipse thinks there's an apk, but then it can't find it. I would try clearing out the bin folder (keep a backup just in case) and running the app on your test device from Eclipse - that should automatically repopulate the bin folder, hopefully including your apk.

Comment: Found the problem, apparently eclipse downloaded another sdk and placed it on my user account and linked to it, that one didn't have the SDK platforms in it, so just changed the path.

Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the Eclipse project files and to import just the code in a new project, better if in a different workspace.

Comment: Tried in the same workspace and nothing, tried on another workspace and nothing, created another workspace and nothing :/